# Button not working on IE11, But works on Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

This is the section of JavaScript that handles the button, When I click on the button in IE11 nothing happens, I don't even get an error in the console. I don't have too much experience with JavaScript so I may not be able to see the obvious.

```
Drupal.behaviors.renoHomeScroll = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      $.scrollify({
        section: '.scroll',
        easing: 'easeOutExpo',
        afterResize: function () {
          Drupal.behaviors.renoHomeScroll.disableScrollify();
        }
      });
      this.disableScrollify();
      $('.go-down', context).click(function (e) {
        scroll = $.scrollify;
        status = $.scrollify.isDisabled();
        if (status == 'false') {
          e.preventDefault();
          $.scrollify.next();
        }
      });
    },
    disableScrollify: function (context, settings) {
      scrolly = $.scrollify;
      status = $.scrollify.isDisabled();

      if ($(window).width() <= 1024) {
        if (status == 'false') {
          $.scrollify.disable();
        }
      } else {
        if (status == 'false') {
          $.scrollify.enable();
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

Comment: Can you add html code of button and what is wrapping the button?

Comment: The button is inside a class like this <a class="go-down"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></a>

Comment: Should your event be attached to a button or to an anchor?

Comment: Its attached to the anchor class .go-down

Comment: Also, I am sure you may be aware if this already by looking at the code that this is in a Drupal site. Not sure if that make any difference.

Comment: I've had a similar issue with a code looking like `<a><button></button></a>`. You should maybe update your question, with only the minimal javascript code that is not working, and a piece oh the html you have. For what I see, there is nothing wrong in your code.

Comment: Sorry we are not using button, just the anchor class .go-down